# how to efficiently appraoch for SPOJ Square free numbers?

Tags: c++

I tried my best to solve Spoj problem [No Squares numbers](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NOSQ/) but I'm getting (TLE). Please tell how to approach. I'm unable to find any proper approach. Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define size 10000004
int mark[size+1];

void sieve()
{
    for(int i=2,k;(k=i*i)<=size;++i)
    {
        for(int j=k;j<=size;j=j+k)
            mark[j]=-1;
    } 
}

int fn(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int i,j,k,cnt=0;
    for(i=a;i<=b;++i)
    {
        j=i;
        if(mark[j]!=-1)
        {
            while(j>0)
            {
                if(j%10==c)
                {
                    cnt+=1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    j=j/10;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main()
{
    sieve();
    int t,a,b,c;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;t++)
    {
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        cout<<fn(a,b,c)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. precompute the prime number table for primes that don't exceed the square root of maximal input number (sqrt(100000) in your case); 2. for every non-prime number in range [a,b] compute the primal decomposition using the prime table, breaking early once the power of any primal component is 2.

Comment: You have several problems in your program - (1) you have the range of possible (a,b) too wide - 10000004 instead of 100000, (2) every number is tried running through the large seived array, squaring your wasted time.